# Use NSUserDefaults with UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, uisegmentedcontrol

This is the code I wrote in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.MisureSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"myKey"] isEqualToString:@"Cm"]) ? (1) : (0);
}
```

This is the action of UISegmentedControl:

```
- (IBAction)MisureAction:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        [standardDefaults setObject:@"Cm" forKey:@"myKey"];
    }
    else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        [standardDefaults setObject:@"Inches" forKey:@"myKey"];
    }
    [standardDefaults synchronize];
}
```

It doesn't work, what is wrong?

Comment: Doesn't work how? What are you expecting and what do you get? Did you debug?

Comment: The UISegmentedControl is in the settings page and I want that if you select it, it will save the selected segment, but when you close and reopen the page, the segmented control doesn't save anything. For example, if you select the 2nd segment and reopen the page, the 1st segment will be selected

Comment: and did you debug the saved value ?

Comment: Yes, I did the debug

Comment: and what did it tell you, were values returned and were they what you expected ?

Comment: There aren't any errors

Comment: Didn't you mixed up the indexes and the "interpreted values" (cm/inches)?

Comment: I don't understand, because i'm a beginner, can you say me, how to use NSUserDefaults with a UISegmentedControl?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad:`, if it's "Cm" that's saved, you put as selected the index "1". In `MisureAction:`, if the index selected is "1", you save "Inches". Seems mixed up. Also, start naming your vars and methods with a lowercase.

Comment: It might be easier to save the index rather than the string value

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work yet

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to save the index rather than any string value.

In AppDelegate / `applicationDidFinishLaunching` register the key/value pair to have a reliable default value

```
NSDictionary *defaultValues = @{@"segmentedIndex":  @0};
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultValues];
```

The default index is 0, change it to the value you prefer.

In `viewDidLoad` read the value

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.MisureSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = [standardDefaults integerForKey:@"segmentedIndex"];
}
```

In `MisureAction`save the value

```
- (IBAction)MisureAction:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [standardDefaults setInteger:sender.selectedSegmentIndex forKey:@"segmentedIndex"];
    [standardDefaults synchronize];
}
```

`segmentedIndex` is an arbitrary key. Use whatever you want, but it must be the same thru all methods.

Comment: It has to. This is standard code. Is the `UISegmentedControl` instance connected properly to the `IBAction`? Registering the key/value pair before using it the first time is very important. I can't believe that so many people forget to do that.

Comment: Set a breakpoint to check if the action is called and check also the index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,and it will work.There is a logic error in your code.

```
- (IBAction)MisureAction:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        [standardDefaults setObject:@"Inches" forKey:@"myKey"];
    }
    else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        [standardDefaults setObject:@"Cm" forKey:@"myKey"];
    }
    [standardDefaults synchronize];
}
```